# how to make my button add an element to the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I want to add a button that adds an element to the total every time I click it:
[image]

the console shows that: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'id' on number '2'

the buttons:

```
 <div key={item.id} className="item">
                    <p  onClick={()=>add(item.id)}>+</p>
                    
                    <p>{item.product}</p>
                    <p>{item.price}</p>
                    <p className="delete" onClick={() => del(item.id)}>&times;</p>
                    
                </div>
```

the delete button(x) is working

the items array:
[image]

and in code:

app.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Items from './components/item/items'
import AddItem from './components/addItem/addItem'
import Total from './components/total/total'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {id:1, product:'Pen', price:2},
      {id:2, product:'Book', price:10}
    ]
  }

  deleteItem = (id) => {
    let items = this.state.items
    let i = items.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    items.splice(i, 1)
    this.setState({items: items})
  }

  
  addItem = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const id = items.length ? items[items.length - 1] + 1 : 1;
    this.setState({ items: [...items, { id }] });
  };
  
  addItem2 = (item) => {
    this.state.items.length > 0 ? (
      item.id = this.state.items[this.state.items.length - 1].id + 1 
    ) : item.id = 1
    console.log(item.id)
    let items = this.state.items
    items.push(item)
    this.setState({items: items})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Product List React App</h1>
        <div className="table">
          <Items items={this.state.items} del={this.deleteItem} add={this.addItem}/>
          <AddItem add={this.addItem2}/>
          <Total items={this.state.items}/>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

the items.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Items = (props) => {
    const {items, del,add} = props;
    let length = items.length
    const ListItem = length ? (
        items.map(item => {
            return(
                <div key={item.id} className="item">
                    <p  onClick={()=>add(item.id)}>+</p>
                    
                    <p>{item.product}</p>
                    <p>{item.price}</p>
                    <p className="delete" onClick={() => del(item.id)}>&times;</p>
                    
                </div>
            )
        })
    ) : (
        <div className="text">There are no items, Try to add some.</div>
    )
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header item">
                <p>quantity</p>
                
                <p>Product</p>
                <p>Price</p>
                
                <p>Edit</p>
                
            </div>
           
            {ListItem}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Items
```

and the total.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Total = (props) => {
    const {items} = props;
    let total = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        total += parseFloat(items[i].price)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <p className="text">Total Price: {total}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Total
```

[image]

Comment: Can I see your `AddItem` component code , please?

Comment: Does your addItem function increase the quantity?

Answer (score 0):

You could do as

```
const updatedItems = this.state.items.filter((_,idx)=> idx!= item))
this.setState({items: updatedItems})
```

Inside the *delItem* method

To add, inside *addItem* method

```
this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, item]})
```

Comment: where in the code?

Comment: Inside the delItem method

Comment: the delete button is working, the + button is not working

Comment: sorry my bad ... Will edit

Comment: Updated the add ...

Comment: sorry but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I think your `addItem` function has problem.

Maybe, when you click `Add` button, `item` in `addItem`function is number like `2`, not object like

```
{
  id : 2
  ...
}
```

So, `item.id = 3` is error because `item` is not object.

You don't need argument `item` because this function only add new item to `items` and doesn't do anything else.

I add code below.

```
addItem = () => {
  const { items } = this.state;
  const id = items.length ? items[items.length - 1] + 1 : 1;
  this.setState({ items: [...items, { id }] });
};
```

I think this answer can help you.

And I don't know the difference between `Add` button and `+` button in every row.

Comment: sorry it gives NaN in total

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: when `addItem ` is called? `Add` button or `+` button?

Comment: when + button is called

Comment: what do you want to happen? Where new item should go? below clicked item? or at the bottom of the list?

Comment: at the bottom of the list at total

Comment: I think my code 'll work  correctly. Did you try it?

Comment: i am sorry but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Mai. I'm not sure if I understood your issues correctly, but I attached my solution codebase. Hope this helpful to you.

```
//  App.js

import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Items from './components/Items'
import AddItem from './components/AddItem'
import Total from './components/Total'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, product: 'Pen', price: 2 },
      { id: 2, product: 'Book', price: 10 }
    ]
  }

  deleteItem = (id) => {
    let items = this.state.items
    let i = items.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    items.splice(i, 1)
    this.setState({ items: items })
  }


  addItem = (itemId) => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const id = items.length ? items[items.length - 1].id + 1 : 1;
    const item = items[itemId - 1];
    this.setState({ items: [...items, { ...item, id }] });
  };

  addItem2 = (item) => {
    this.state.items.length > 0 ? (
      item.id = this.state.items[this.state.items.length - 1].id + 1
    ) : item.id = 1
    console.log(item.id)
    let items = this.state.items
    items.push(item)
    this.setState({ items: items })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Product List React App</h1>
        <div className="table">
          <Items items={this.state.items} del={this.deleteItem} add={this.addItem} />
          <AddItem add={this.addItem2} />
          <Total items={this.state.items} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
//  Total.js

import React from 'react';

const Total = (props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].price !== undefined) {
      total += parseFloat(items[i].price)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="text">Total Price: {total}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Total
```